# How can I make my RStudio movie budget diagram more readable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help to make a diagram more readable in RStudio.

I downloaded a movie dataset from Kaggle (IMDB Top 250 Movies) and I wanted to make a diagram where the x axis is the "Genre" and the y axis is the "Budget", and the color is mapped to "Genre" also the size is mapped to "Budget".
The Problem is that the budgets in the Dataset are written in dollars so instead of 20 million it is 20000000 so there is a lot of budgets.

I typed this code:

```
ggplot(data=movies, aes(x=genre, y=budget, 
                        color=genre, size=budget)) +
  geom_point()
```

The Result:

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of budgets and it makes the diagram really inefficient.

How can I make this diagram better? in other words, how can I modify the y axis that it will have less numbers? For example, from bottom of y axis 50M  100M  150M  200M etc...

Comment: Your budget variable is not a numeric variable, but encoded as characters or a factor. You probably need to fix how you are reading in the data, or (less ideal) convert to numeric like so `movies$budget_num <- as.numeric(as.character(movies$budget))`. This will fix both your y-axis and your size scale.

Comment: Oh I see why it is numeric. Some of the budgets still have the `$` sign included, some have `EM` or `RF` in front, some say `"Not Available"`. You need to clean your data.